# Heroku deployment fails on missing SQL table

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have my app deployed on Heroku and I'm struggling with an error message I get there, but not on my local machine. (They're both running exactly the same code although admittedly the environments are different.  One important difference is that locally I build on the same machine as I execute.  Heroku does not.)

I've inserted some print statements that attempt to isolate the problem.  On my local machine running `heroku local` these messages come out as:

```
6:06:38 PM web.1 |  DisasterResponse.db successfully opened.
6:06:38 PM web.1 |  Schema Names: ['main']
6:06:38 PM web.1 |  Table Names: ['MessageCategorization']
```

which is great. There's the table, 'MessageCategorization', I create in my release script. Unfortunately that table is missing when I run the code on the Heroku dyno. The same lines come out as:

```
Oct 01 19:51:38‌disaster-message-triage‌‌app/web.1‌ DisasterResponse.db successfully opened.
Oct 01 19:51:38 ‌disaster-message-triage‌ ‌app/web.1‌ Schema Names: ['main']
Oct 01 19:51:38 ‌disaster-message-triage‌ ‌app/web.1‌ Table Names: []
```

Here you can see that schema 'main' is present but and I have no 'MessageCategorization' table.

If you're curious you can examine my repo at https://github.com/manifolded/FigureEightDisasterResponse

I'd welcome advice on how to further diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I've noticed is that your **release** commands are executed after each successful build.

But... Release commands are post-build and not part of the build, meaning that once your build is complete a snapshot of the files at that time are the ones that make it to the running dynos.

You can examine the dyno file structure by running `heroku run bash`, and then running bash commands like `cd`, `ls`, etc.

**Note**:any changes you make this way are temporary and last only during this one-off session

You can either make the release script part of the build by using a *bash buildpack* (Not sure if it exists), or use a persistent postgres database that heroku provides.[See here](https://data.heroku.com/)

Comment: So your saying the process is not build -> release -> run?  This would imply that files generated during release would not be available on run.  That could do it.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, make the DB generation part of the build to achieve what you're trying

Comment: Heroku agrees with you.  "Release phase is not suitable for tasks that require filesystem persistence, as filesystem changes during release phase will not be deployed to your app’s dyno formation (the dyno filesystem is ephemeral). Asset compilation should happen during builds. Release phase can be used to upload the compiled assets to a CDN."   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase

Comment: Yeah, that's what wasn't right, it's a cool project, have you deployed it yet?

Comment: I used https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/weibeld/heroku-buildpack-run to allow me to run a script during the build phase.  This worked perfectly and solved the problem!  Thank you so much for helping me diagnose this one.

Comment: It's not deployed yet since I'm faced with a different error.  I'll let you know.

Comment: The app is up!  Thank you so much for your help.  It made all the difference. 
 https://disaster-message-triage.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Glad to know I was of help and your awesome project is up!